# Cannot deploy REST API with Python on Azure

Tags: python, rest, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy simple Azure web application. I create it exactly as described here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python

but replaced code in **main.py** with following (and update **requirements.txt** of course):

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
todos = {}


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}


class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Everything works fine locally, but there are issues with deployed version:

-- http://my-app-name-here.azurewebsites.net is just fine and prints {'hello': 'world'} as expected

-- other commands provided by TodoSimple are not accessible.

For example following query

```
curl http://my-app-name-here.azurewebsites.net/todo -d "data=Remember the milk" -X PUT
```

would result with "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." response.

**Update:** it's all fine when ran locally

```
$curl http://localhost:5000/todo -d "data=Remember the milk" -X PUT
{
    "todo": "Remember the milk"
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing with this app deployment?

**Update2:** approach without flask_restful won't work either:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    return 'The data.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Calling http://my-app-name-here.azurewebsites.net/data results in "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." message again.

Comment: are you sure the path is what you are expecting it to be? azure doesnt alter behavior of your flask app in any way

Comment: @4c74356b41 well, I'm sure it is because I can get my "helloworld" response from main webpage.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've updated the question providing the working local command example.

Comment: i suspect it has something to do with how flask_restful handles the routes. i wasnt using it with flask and was just registering flask routes and it was working perfectly, you can take a look at what I was using, [it](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/FlaskWebProject/views.py) might help

Comment: @4c74356b41 I tried approach without flask_restful (see update2), it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Try referring to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world/issues/4), I won't post it as an answer but I believe it'll work.

Comment: @MilanVelebit Thank you, it looks like a right direction.

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue also. Is there a solution? In my scenario, i can't get any page to load other than the x.azurewebsites.net which is simply the microsoft "Your App Service app is up and running" page. I don't even have any views, simply a blank Flask app that returns hello world. Why is there a view at all?